# Why do I get two different answers for reading the balance of an ethereum account?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3py, ganache

I was trying to read the balance of a few Ethereum test accounts in two different ways and got two different answers, but not for all accounts. More specifically, I was setting up a test Ethereum network with Ganache and deployed the following smart contract using Remix which was connected to the test network. By default the first account was used for the deployment transaction.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Test {
    
    function balanceOf(address addr) external view returns (uint) {
        return addr.balance;
    }
    
}
```

Calling the `balanceOf` function in Remix on the accounts provided by Ganache worked like a charm. Then I was running the following Python code using the latest Web3.py library to call the `balanceOf` function on all accounts.

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545'))   # connecting to the Ganache Ethereum network

def toEther(balance):
    return web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether')

# connecting to the 'Test' contract
abi = json.loads('[ { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "address", "name": "addr", "type": "address" } ], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "uint256", "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" } ]')
contract_address = '0x3038871e10654B87858Be4952B26bd7607Cb0c8b'   # this will be different for you
contract = web3.eth.contract(abi=abi, address=contract_address)

# printing balances
for account in web3.eth.accounts: 
    print(f'balance of {account}:  {toEther(contract.functions.balanceOf(account).call())}  versus {toEther(web3.eth.getBalance(account))}')
```

As you can see, the balance is computed in two ways:

1. by calling the `balanceOf` function of the contract producing the first number,
2. by calling the `web3.eth.getBalance` method of Web3 producing the second number.
   The result was this

```
balance of 0x76290BDDea6C156A7F364aBB952aE29D49C593bE:  180143885.09682616  versus 99.99799366
balance of 0x3BFCAC461d922e3b4504BB5fc59dA5546a767617:  100  versus 100
balance of 0xD2AA30E855eb3F9B64A14Bb1a4EE4C4Ad645dA58:  100  versus 100
...
```

As you can see, the `balanceOf` function of the contract produced a wrong result for the first address. The `web3.eth.getBalance` method shows the correct result (100 - gas for deployment). I was deploying the contract again without rebooting the Ganache network and got the following result (still calling the first deployment, but it didn't matter):

```
balance of 0x76290BDDea6C156A7F364aBB952aE29D49C593bE:  180143885.0988325  versus 99.99598732
balance of 0x3BFCAC461d922e3b4504BB5fc59dA5546a767617:  100  versus 100
balance of 0xD2AA30E855eb3F9B64A14Bb1a4EE4C4Ad645dA58:  100  versus 100
...
```

As you can see, the first value has surprisingly gone up by the gas fee (about 0.002) whereas the second one has gone down by the same amount, as expected, due to the second deployment transaction. Finally, I've deployed the contract again using the second account instead of the first one. Again, both balance computations give the correct result, except for the first account:

```
balance of 0x76290BDDea6C156A7F364aBB952aE29D49C593bE:  180143885.0988325  versus 99.99598732
balance of 0x3BFCAC461d922e3b4504BB5fc59dA5546a767617:  99.99799366  versus 99.99799366
balance of 0xD2AA30E855eb3F9B64A14Bb1a4EE4C4Ad645dA58:  100  versus 100
```

I'm a novice in blockchain technology and I was wondering if anyone can explain to me the strange behaviour of the `balanceOf` function for the first account (only!!!) using Web3. As I said, calling the function in Remix always gives the correct result.

PS: This is not a Python problem. I made the same observation using the Web3.js library.